# Display highcharts graph with a lot of data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have an angularjs application and I use [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) to display some graphs. I got the data from an http request and I modify the data to display  them in the graph. 
If I receive just a just some data, it's ok, it works but when I receive a lot of data, the highcharts component take a long time to display the data. And in this time the browser in freezed.

In my controller, I have:

```
widgetCtrl.chartDataLine = {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Power Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: 'Date time'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Power (W)'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    options: {
        exporting: {
            enabled: true,
            allowHTML: true,
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: null,
                    onclick: function () {
                        this.exportChart();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    plotOptions:{
        series:{
            turboThreshold:60000 // larger threshold or set to 0 to disable
        }
    },

    series: []
};
```

I call the data like that:

```
var getMetrics = function (searchText) {
    var param = {
        target: searchText
    };
    xcsDatasource.get('beo').callAction('getPowerMetrics', param.target, widgetCtrl.pickerFrom.date, widgetCtrl.pickerTo.date).then(
        function (result) {
            widgetCtrl.metrics = result;
            widgetCtrl.metricsAsString = JSON.stringify(result);
            var t = getChartData(result);


            widgetCtrl.chartDataLine.series = angular.copy(t);
            console.log(widgetCtrl.chartDataLine);
            //widgetCtrl.chartDataArea.series = getChartData(result);

        },
        function () {
            widgetCtrl.metrics = {};
            widgetCtrl.metricsAsString = '';
        }
    );
};
```

And this is my html:

```
<div ng-if="config.linechart" class="graph-container col-sm-12">
    <highchart id="chart1" config="pwrDashboardViewCtrl.chartDataLine"></highchart>
</div>
```

Do you have an idea how I can do to continue to load the grapph without freezing the browser ?

Comment: Have you considered using the **boost module** (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module)?

Comment: I added the boost but I don't really see a difference...

Comment: Could you provide a minimal live demo that reproduces the problem (jsfiddle ideally)?